# Calling different functions based on where a user taps the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am building a simple app that has a ball that falls from the top of the screen and must hit the corresponding color on the color wheel below. At the moment the color wheel will spin 1 time and integrate its rawValue by 1 each time the user taps the screen.

I would like the color wheel to spin in the right direction when the user taps the right side of the screen and in the left direction when the user taps the left side of the screen. I am having trouble figuring out how to "split the screen" so a particular rotation function is called when the user taps the particular side.

This is the code I have for turning the wheel and matching it to the ball color...

//Turn wheel function

```
func turnWheel() {
    colorSwitch.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi/2, duration: 0.25))
    if let newState = SwitchState(rawValue: switchState.rawValue + 1){
        switchState = newState
    } else {
        switchState = .red
    }
}
```

//Spawn ball function

```
func spawnBall(){
    currentColorIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))

    let ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball"), color: PlayColors.colors[currentColorIndex!], size: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
    ball.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    ball.name = "Ball"
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    ball.zPosition = ZPositions.ball
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ballCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.switchCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none

    addChild(ball)
}
```

//Physics contact delegate

```
extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | 
 contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask  
    if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.switchCategory {
        if let ball = contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Ball" ?
            contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode : contact.bodyB.node as?
            SKSpriteNode {
            if currentColorIndex == switchState.rawValue {
                score += 1
                updateScoreLabel()
                let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                generator.impactOccurred()
                ball.removeFromParent()
                self.spawnBall()
            } else {
                gameOver()
                explosion(ball: ball)
                let generator2 = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                generator2.impactOccurred()
            }
         }
      }    
   }
}
```

In addition to making the wheel turn in the opposite direction, I also need it to still be able to match the color. At the moment the colors are stored in enums and the 'correct match' occurs when the rawValue of the wheel matches the array value of the ball.

//Ball colors

```
enum PlayColors {
static let colors = [
    UIColor(red: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1.0),
    UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 196/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1.0),
    UIColor(red: 46/255, green: 204/255, blue: 113/255, alpha: 1.0),
    UIColor(red: 52/255, green: 152/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1.0)
    ]
}
enum SwitchState: Int {
    case red, yellow, green, blue
}
```

Comment: You can subclass your view with a parent class of UIControl. UIControl has delegate methods for listen touch events by which you can get touch location on the screen and calculate it's location in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to split the screen in two. To do this, you want to determine which side of the screen the user is clicking. You can do this by following the code below.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch:UITouch = (touches.first as UITouch?)!
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

     if touchLocation.x < self.frame.size.width / 2 {
            // Left side of the screen
            // Call function to rotate wheel left
     }else{
            // Right side of the screen
            // Call function to rotate wheel right
        }
    }
}
```

In regards to your `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`, this is all sorts of messy and hard to understand.

I believe you should create a class called `Ball`. Something like this (I have transferred over your code from your spawnBallFunction).

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode{

        var currentColorIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
        var currIndex: Int {
            get {
                return currentColorIndex
            }
            set {
                currentColorIndex = newValue
            }
        }

    init(){

        let ballTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball")
        super.init(texture: ballTexture, color: PlayColors.colors[currentColorIndex!], size: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))

        self.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        self.name = "Ball"
        self.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
        self.zPosition = ZPositions.ball
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ballCategory
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.switchCategory
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now in your `spawnBall` function, you can do this:

```
func spawnBall(){
    let ball = Ball() 
    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

Here is what I did to try and clean up your contact function:

```
extension GameScene{

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

      var ball: Ball
      var otherNode: SKSpriteNode //not sure what this other node is by looking at your code

      if(contact.bodyA.name == "ball"){
          ball = contact.bodyA.node! as! Ball
          otherNode = contact.bodyB.node! as! SKSpriteNode
      }
      else{
          otherNode = contact.bodyA.node! as! SKSpriteNode
          ball = contact.bodyB.node! as! Ball
      }

      if ball.currentColorIndex == switchState.rawValue {

          score += 1
          updateScoreLabel()
          let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
          generator.impactOccurred()
          ball.removeFromParent()
          self.spawnBall()
       } else {
          gameOver()
          explosion(ball: ball)
          let generator2 = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
          generator2.impactOccurred()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following errors when trying to implement the Ball class:

1.)
'self' used in property access 'frame' before 'super.init' call

2.)
'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Comment: @EricFriedman I have updated the Ball class. I added the super.init function which I previously had forgotten. Take a look!